# Find all objects that are not used in VS 2010 Pro so they can be safely removed?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to go through inherited code and find find out what objects are not being used anywhere so I can safely delete them.  Is there a tool in VS 2010 Pro that enables this?  I have been just doing a Find, but I find that this at times may be misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JetBrains ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can do this for you. You'll still need to be intelligent about removing classes, though. If you're using and DI containers or configuration through external files I've seen it think things are not used, when in fact they are.

Here's an example of how it reports this in a file (there's also solution-wide analysis that can be run):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the example.  Is it the solution wide analysis that causes Resharper to be so slow (Super slow)? I was using the trial and it was hogging down my machine.  The example you provided will only tell if it is not being used in the current file correct?  It could still be used in other file?  Just double-checking.

Comment: It actually checks if the class is used anywhere in your solution. It does this for properties and methods as well, so you can trim your objects down if you can't eliminate them entirely. For performance, if you're allowing it to cache its results it shouldn't be *too* bad. You might just have a huge solution or a slow dev box?

Comment: Dev box is not bad, the solution is just huge, as I pointed out to Oded, the original developers had a quantity over quality mindset.

Answer (score 2):

Resharper has this feature - if you turn on [solution wide analysis](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__Solution-Wide_Analysis.html), any member of a class that is *not* used will have its name grayed out.

You do need to be careful if you use an IoC container of some sort, as it may be using a member at runtime but static analysis of the code base will not be able to discover this usage.

Comment: I was using a Resharper Trial license, but the thing is sooooooooo slow.

Comment: No IoC containers here. This went from a classic asp app to a .net 2.0 app and it was a matter of quantity over quality.

Comment: Do you know if Refactor Pro! does this as well?

Comment: @Xaisoft - It doesn't, not yet, though they will probably end up implementing it. See this: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/AS3994.aspx